# How do I debug AWS Api Gateway & Lambda's "AWS/ApiGateway 5XXError"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I have an API Gateway resource that runs a lambda function.  I'm calling the API Gateway resource using the AWS Generated SDK from my Api Gateway.

Here's the portion of the stacktrace from my client that seems relevant:

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientException: {"message": "Internal server error"} (Service: DevnetcountableClient; Status Code: 500; Error Code: null; Request ID: 348e8f98-6f55-11e6-97f6-098c2caf220f)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.handleResponse(ApiClientHandler.java:255) at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientHandler.invoke(ApiClientHandler.java:88)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
    at $Proxy1.accountCreatePost(Unknown Source)
```

Now looking at the AWS console, within my Api Gateway Dashboard I see the requests coming in and resulting in "AWS/ApiGateway 5XXError".  However there are 0 logs (that I can find).  My lambda function does NOT appear to be called, and no lambda logs are shown.

Right now this is what my lambda looks like:

```
module.exports.createAccount = function(event, context, cb) {
    console.log('createAccount');
    console.log(event);
    console.log(context);
    console.log(cb);
    cb(null, {status: 'SUCCESS', message: 'I ran!'});
};
```

What can I do to debug this?

Edit:  Okay here is the cloudformation script that's throwing everything together.

```
{
   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion":"2010-09-09",
   "Description":"The AWS CloudFormation template for this Serverless application",
   "Resources":{
      "ServerlessDeploymentBucket":{
         "Type":"AWS::S3::Bucket"
      },
      "IamRoleLambda":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Role",
         "Properties":{
            "AssumeRolePolicyDocument":{
               "Version":"2012-10-17",
               "Statement":[
                  {
                     "Effect":"Allow",
                     "Principal":{
                        "Service":[
                           "lambda.amazonaws.com"
                        ]
                     },
                     "Action":[
                        "sts:AssumeRole"
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "Path":"/"
         }
      },
      "IamPolicyLambda":{
         "Type":"AWS::IAM::Policy",
         "Properties":{
            "PolicyName":"dev-coolsoftware-lambda",
            "PolicyDocument":{
               "Version":"2012-10-17",
               "Statement":[
                  {
                     "Effect":"Allow",
                     "Action":[
                        "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                        "logs:CreateLogStream",
                        "logs:PutLogEvents"
                     ],
                     "Resource":"arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:*:*"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "Roles":[
               {
                  "Ref":"IamRoleLambda"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "createAccount":{
         "Type":"AWS::Lambda::Function",
         "Properties":{
            "Code":{
               "S3Bucket":{
                  "Ref":"ServerlessDeploymentBucket"
               },
               "S3Key":"coolsoftware-1472853507538.zip"
            },
            "FunctionName":"coolsoftware-dev-createAccount",
            "Handler":"handler.createAccount",
            "MemorySize":128,
            "Role":{
               "Fn::GetAtt":[
                  "IamRoleLambda",
                  "Arn"
               ]
            },
            "Runtime":"nodejs4.3",
            "Timeout":30
         }
      },
      "RestApiApigEvent":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
         "Properties":{
            "Name":"dev-coolsoftware"
         }
      },
      "ResourceApigEventCreateaccountAccount":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
         "Properties":{
            "ParentId":{
               "Fn::GetAtt":[
                  "RestApiApigEvent",
                  "RootResourceId"
               ]
            },
            "PathPart":"account",
            "RestApiId":{
               "Ref":"RestApiApigEvent"
            }
         }
      },
      "PutMethodApigEventCreateaccountAccount":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
         "Properties":{
            "AuthorizationType":"AWS_IAM",
            "HttpMethod":"PUT",
            "MethodResponses":[
               {
                  "ResponseModels":{
                     "application/json":"AccountCreationResponseModel"
                  },
                  "ResponseParameters":{

                  },
                  "StatusCode":"200"
               }
            ],
            "RequestParameters":{

            },
            "Integration":{
               "IntegrationHttpMethod":"POST",
               "Type":"AWS",
               "Uri":{
                  "Fn::Join":[
                     "",
                     [
                        "arn:aws:apigateway:",
                        {
                           "Ref":"AWS::Region"
                        },
                        ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/",
                        {
                           "Fn::GetAtt":[
                              "createAccount",
                              "Arn"
                           ]
                        },
                        "/invocations"
                     ]
                  ]
               },
               "RequestTemplates":{
                  "application/json":"\n            #define( $loop )\n              {\n              #foreach($key in $map.keySet())\n                  \"$util.escapeJavaScript($key)\":\n                    \"$util.escapeJavaScript($map.get($key))\"\n                    #if( $foreach.hasNext ) , #end\n              #end\n              }\n            #end\n            {\n              \"body\": $input.json(\"$\"),\n              \"method\": \"$context.httpMethod\",\n              \"principalId\": \"$context.authorizer.principalId\",\n              \"stage\": \"$context.stage\",\n\n              #set( $map = $input.params().header )\n              \"headers\": $loop,\n\n              #set( $map = $input.params().querystring )\n              \"query\": $loop,\n\n              #set( $map = $input.params().path )\n              \"path\": $loop,\n\n              #set( $map = $context.identity )\n              \"identity\": $loop,\n\n              #set( $map = $stageVariables )\n              \"stageVariables\": $loop\n            }\n          "
               },
               "IntegrationResponses":[
                  {
                     "StatusCode":"200",
                     "ResponseParameters":{

                     },
                     "ResponseTemplates":{
                        "application/json":""
                     }
                  }
               ]
            },
            "ResourceId":{
               "Ref":"ResourceApigEventCreateaccountAccount"
            },
            "RestApiId":{
               "Ref":"RestApiApigEvent"
            },
            "RequestModels":{
               "application/json":"AccountCreationRequestModel"
            }
         }
      },
      "DeploymentApigEvent1472853508283":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
         "Properties":{
            "RestApiId":{
               "Ref":"RestApiApigEvent"
            },
            "StageName":"dev"
         },
         "DependsOn":[
            "PutMethodApigEventCreateaccountAccount"
         ]
      },
      "createAccountApigPermission":{
         "Type":"AWS::Lambda::Permission",
         "Properties":{
            "FunctionName":{
               "Fn::GetAtt":[
                  "createAccount",
                  "Arn"
               ]
            },
            "Action":"lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Principal":"apigateway.amazonaws.com"
         }
      },
      "DynamoDBTableAccounts":{
         "Type":"AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
         "DeletionPolicy":"Retain",
         "Properties":{
            "TableName":"dev-coolsoftware-accounts",
            "ProvisionedThroughput":{
               "ReadCapacityUnits":1,
               "WriteCapacityUnits":1
            },
            "AttributeDefinitions":[
               {
                  "AttributeName":"accountid",
                  "AttributeType":"S"
               }
            ],
            "KeySchema":[
               {
                  "AttributeName":"accountid",
                  "KeyType":"HASH"
               }
            ]
         }
      },
      "AccountCreationRequestModel":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Model",
         "Properties":{
            "RestApiId":{
               "Ref":"RestApiApigEvent"
            },
            "ContentType":"application/json",
            "Description":"Schema for AccountCreationRequestModel",
            "Name":"AccountCreationRequestModel",
            "Schema":{
               "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
               "title":"AccountCreationRequestModel",
               "type":"object",
               "properties":{
                  "publickey":{
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "deviceid":{
                     "type":"string"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "AccountCreationResponseModel":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Model",
         "Properties":{
            "RestApiId":{
               "Ref":"RestApiApigEvent"
            },
            "ContentType":"application/json",
            "Description":"Schema for AccountCreationResponseModel",
            "Name":"AccountCreationResponseModel",
            "Schema":{
               "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
               "title":"AccountCreationResponseModel",
               "type":"object",
               "properties":{
                  "status":{
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "message":{
                     "type":"string"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "FailureResponseModel":{
         "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Model",
         "Properties":{
            "RestApiId":{
               "Ref":"RestApiApigEvent"
            },
            "ContentType":"application/json",
            "Description":"Schema for FailureResponseModel",
            "Name":"FailureResponseModel",
            "Schema":{
               "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
               "title":"FailureResponseModel",
               "type":"object",
               "properties":{
                  "status":{
                     "type":"string"
                  },
                  "message":{
                     "type":"string"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "Outputs":{
      "ServerlessDeploymentBucketName":{
         "Value":{
            "Ref":"ServerlessDeploymentBucket"
         }
      },
      "Function1Arn":{
         "Description":"Lambda function info",
         "Value":{
            "Fn::GetAtt":[
               "createAccount",
               "Arn"
            ]
         }
      },
      "ServiceEndpoint":{
         "Description":"URL of the service endpoint",
         "Value":{
            "Fn::Join":[
               "",
               [
                  "https://",
                  {
                     "Ref":"RestApiApigEvent"
                  },
                  ".execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev"
               ]
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Edit 2:  When I test the endpoint using API Gateway's test feature in the AWS Console everything works great :/

Edit 3: Updated the cloudformation script again--still not working.

Comment: I got these kinds of errors from missing integrations. But it's hard to figure out without seeing how you created the gateway/lambda.

Comment: Hm, that could be it.  I generated it using the Serverless Framework, but I'm attempting to include request/response models, authentication, and enable "Invoke with caller credentials" through a cloudformation script.  Maybe that's what's breaking it.  Serverless framework does everything through cloudformation.  I'll take a look at the template.  Thanks

Comment: @RhythmicFistman I've added my cloudformation script, would you mind taking a look at it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**How to Debug:**

1. Create an IAM role to allow API Gateway to push logs to CloudWatch. The role must have the following policy attach:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:GetLogEvents",
                "logs:FilterLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

With the following trust policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. In API Gateway console for your API's region: Go to settings >>> Enter in the ARN of the API Gateway-CloudWatch logging role >>> click 'Save'
3. Go to the stage of your API. Under 'CloudWatch Settings', select 'Enable CloudWatch Logs'. Set 'Log level' to 'INFO'. Select 'Log full requests/responses data'.

[image: enabling cloudwatch logs]

4. Redeploy your API to that stage: Go to the 'Resources' tab for your API. Select Actions >>> Deploy API.
5. Make requests, wait a few minutes, and see what the logs say (in CloudWatch).

**The Error:**

[image: The error]

**The Cause:**

Once I enabled "Invoke with caller credentials" using `Credentials: 'arn:aws:iam::*:user/*'`, the caller's IAM role didn't have access to invoke the lambda function.  This resulted in the 500 error.  Once I gave the caller's IAM role access, everything started to work properly.

Comment: There's now a managed policy that you can use, rather than creating your own. It's called `AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs`.

Comment: Could you give more details on how you solve the error 500, and especially, what's inside the caller's IAM role access? Thanks.

Comment: I am wondering how to hit breakpoint on my local machine while my code is running in AWS Api Gateway ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

What does the API Gateway Log show? does it show "Invalid permissions on Lambda function"? I think you'll need to include the permission creation (resource) in the CloudFormation Template. Here is one of mine:

```
"PERMISSIONGET": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
        "Properties": {
            "FunctionName": "createCabinet",
            "Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction",
            "Principal": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
            "SourceArn": {
                "Fn::Join": [
                    "",
                    [
                        "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:87875636623:",
                        {
                            "Ref": "APIGATEWAY"
                        },
                        "/*/GET/*"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        "DependsOn": "APIDEPLOYMENT"
    }
```

Comment: I already resolved this (see my answer below).  It was the callers credentials that needed permission to invoke the lambda function because in API gateway I had enabled "Invoke with caller credentials"

Answer (score 0):

In case some one in need.

Following link explain how to enable cloudwatch logs for debugging api gateway issues.

https://kennbrodhagen.net/2016/07/23/how-to-enable-logging-for-api-gateway/